# Searching tags, documentation error

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, help-pages

In [How do I find topics I'm interested in?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/interesting-topics), under **Search tags**,

> If you're looking for questions about multiple topics, you can also search by tags. Our site search recognizes tags enclosed in brackets (like this: `[tag]`), as well as the search operators `AND` and `OR`. The default operator is `AND` – i.e., searching for "[tag1] [tag2]" returns posts tagged with both.

The `AND` operator, if included, doesn't really work.

A search with `[house-rules] AND [senate-rules]`. Gives,

> Results for and tagged with [house-rules](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-rules) [senate-rules](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/senate-rules)

Note that "and" in the above is the word "and" appearing in questions and answers.

There are 12 results, including 4 questions and 8 answers.

Removing the "AND" gives 5 questions and no answers, because one of the questions does not contain the word "and".

(The `OR` search operator works, but care is required if one uses `OR` in combination with other tags intended to be `AND`ed or excluded.)

---

It being the case that the "`AND` operator" doesn't work, the mention of `AND` as a search operator should be removed and note that the "The default behavior is to `AND` ...".

Comment: The `AND` operator functionality seems to have been [removed a long time ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160100). I've added the status review tag because regular mods can't edit the help pages.

Comment: The article has been updated!